# Laravel empty page with no error calling route's method

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes, magnific-popup

I have a methods that return `base64 data image` to a view after making a `GET` request to `www.website.com/preview/{id}`.

It is called by an `<a>` tag inside **view.blade.php**:

```
<a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="{{url(Config::get("app.previewPath") , $encrypted)}}" >
    <img class="issue_img" src="{{App\Http\Classes\RepositoryUtil::getSmallImage($encrypted)}}" alt="{{ $name }}">
</a>
```

It work well if I declare a `GET` route with the code function inside **routes.php**:

```
Route::get(Config::get("app.previewPath") . "/{id}", function(\Request $request, $encrypted){
        // ... some code ...
        $base64 = \App\Http\Classes\RepositoryUtil::retriveImage($encrypted);
        @readfile($base64);
});
```

But if I move the same code inside a controller's method, it return a blank page!

```
Route::get(Config::get("app.previewPath") . "/{id}", "MyController@getPreview");
```

**MyController.php**

```
public static function getPreview(\Request $request, $encrypted){
    // ... same code as routes.php ...
    $base64 = \App\Http\Classes\RepositoryUtil::retriveImage($encrypted);
    @readfile($base64);
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hello Daan, thanks for reply, I tried but it doesn't work..

Comment: @Tenaciousd93 Have you checked the Laravel error log in `storage/logs/laravel.log` to see what's the error being thrown?

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa What's the logic behind your comment? Because PHP namespaces are not equivalent to a filesystem, you can't just put `..` in front and go up one level (if that's your suggestion).

Comment: Sorry misjudged it. @Bogdan

Comment: @Bogdan nothing new in `laravel.log`

Comment: Remove the error suppresion `@` from the `readfile` function call and see if you get an error reported then.

Comment: Just tried, no editing made in log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, it was a "distraction error".

I leave a **middleware** enabled in all methods of the controller, and it fails printing `dd("Not authorized!");` without `return` before it.

It didn't return nothing without any errors!

I restrincted the middleware only to selected actions.

Thanks for support.